# ARCore - How to detect single horizontal plane only

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I am working with ARCore in one of my project. There, I need to detect a plane and place some objects(Anchors) on it.

In my onResume function, I created a AR session and able to detect only horizontal planes using Session configuration.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (arSceneView == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (arSceneView.getSession() == null) {
        // If the session wasn't created yet, don't resume rendering.
        // This can happen if ARCore needs to be updated or permissions are not granted yet.
        try {
            session = DemoUtils.createArSession(this, installRequested);
            mArConfig = session.getConfig();
            mArConfig.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.HORIZONTAL);
            mArConfig.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
            session.configure(mArConfig);

            if (session == null) {
                installRequested = DemoUtils.hasCameraPermission(this);
                return;
            } else {
                arSceneView.setupSession(session);
            }
        } catch (UnavailableException e) {
            DemoUtils.handleSessionException(this, e);
        }
    }

    try {
        arSceneView.resume();
    } catch (CameraNotAvailableException ex) {
        DemoUtils.displayError(this, "Unable to get camera", ex);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if (arSceneView.getSession() != null) {
        try {
            session.resume();
        } catch (CameraNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I get many horizontal planes. My requirement is to get only one horizontal plane which is detected first.

So, I tried to Disable plane finding mode in setOnUpdateListener as following,

```
arSceneView.getScene().setOnUpdateListener(frameTime -> {
        if (loadingMessageSnackbar == null){
            return;
        }

        Frame frame = arSceneView.getArFrame();

        if (frame == null){
            return;
        }

        if (frame.getCamera().getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING){
            return;
        }

        for (Plane plane : frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane.class)){
            if (plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING){
                Config c =arSceneView.getSession().getConfig();
                c.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.DISABLED);
                arSceneView.getSession().configure(c);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here, once the plane is detected it is getting hide.

Can anyone suggest any method to get the first detected horizontal plane and place objects in that plane only??

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: I am not an Android developer but i have a question? Cant you use `Session.getAllTrackables` instead of `getupdatedTrackables` . When you got 1 trackable plane from Session, disable plane finding right away.

Comment: Thank you. We can use that, but the the thing is after we disable plane finding, detected plane also not there..

Comment: Well i noticed the same thing in Unity. As a work around what i did was instead of creating my anchors using `Trackable.createAnchor` i used `Session.createAnchor(detectedPlanes[0].CenterPose)` then i disabled plane finding my anchored object was still at the surface and tracked properly. Some drifts might occur but it happens with ARCore all the time even with plane tracking

Comment: I changed it as follows inside **for loop** like your method. But still the detected plane get hide. Is there any mistakes here?? `arSceneView.getSession().createAnchor(plane.getCenterPose());
Config c =arSceneView.getSession().getConfig();                              c.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.DISABLED);
arSceneView.getSession().configure(c);`

Comment: No there is no problem with this. The detected plane will get hide but if you place and anchor objects to that plane they will still be rendered after you disable plane detection. You can also check this [link](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/126)

Comment: Still not working for me. Are you sure that we can create the the anchors even after the plane detection is disabled? `arSceneView.getSession().createAnchor(plane.getCenterPose());` with this, we are creating the anchor on the CenterPose of the plane. we don`t store the detected plane anywhere. Do I need to use Unity to have a plane in the CenterPose we detected??

Comment: You can create anchors anytime if you use `Session.createAnchor(Pose pose)` but what i am saying is you first create the anchor then put all your content models objects whatever under that anchor it will still be tracked after you disable plane detection. Plane will be gone but all the content you put at plane position will be there.

Comment: Thank you... Yes, you are correct.  I can create an anchor using the session. But, my requirement is to place the anchor objects on the touch locations of a **single plane**. Now i am using `hit.createAnchor` to create anchor on the touch location of the plane. If I disable the plane detection by above method I ll not get the `hit` and will not get the touch `pose`.  So, my need is single surface to place objects, without other planes interruption???

Comment: @Angathan Found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
Config config = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().getConfig();
config.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.DISABLED);  
arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().configure(config);
```